# unable to register a dll in windows 7 enterprise x64

Tags: c++, dll, regsvr32

trying to register a DLL built with visual c++ 2005 and another DLL built with visual c++ 2008.
the system config is windows 7 enterprise 64 bit
I tried running regsvr32 from default location and from `c:\windows\syswow64`

in either case I'm getting the error
 [image: Error message when i try to register the DLL]

I have C++ redistributable runtime library installed for 2005, 2005 SP1, 2008 for x86 and x64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VITInterface.DLL probably depends on an another DLL. Try [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to see what else your DLL needs.